# How to Redirect my current Location in google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

how can I redirect my current Location when I open the Google Map

here is my code in SetUpMap()

```
      private void setUpMap() {
             mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
             mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

And also how can I change the Marker ? I only get that blue circle in my location. I want to change it to a Pin

Comment: What do you mean with redirect? Do you want to change the position of the marker?

Comment: Yes because when I open the google map it shows the center of the map, To show my location I need to click the button. I don't want to click the button I just want to show my Location if I open google map

Comment: @TaengooKim please accept an answer if it helps to further help the community.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to open map with your location through any activity then use this code    

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
    startActivity(intent);


If you are using Google map then using location find lat long and pass this lat long in maps object
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current location of the user as soon as your `Map` is ready and you need to animate the camera like this

```
Location location = this.mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();

    if (location != null) {

        LatLng target = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraPosition position = this.mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition();

        Builder builder = new CameraPosition.Builder();
        builder.zoom(15);
        builder.target(target);

        this.mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(builder.build()));

      }
```

So, `getMyLocation()` has to fetch the location of the user. Use can use `PROVIDERS` to fetch the location. You can also listen to location using `LocationListener` using `GoogleApiClient`. Kindly read the documentation of [Getting the Last Known Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and [Receiving Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) before posting here.

To give the custom marker for your location there is something called `addMarker`

```
mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLogitude()))
                      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

Comment: Do I put this code in private void setUpMapIfNeeded() ??

Comment: No you should not do like this. Once the `Map` is ready then you need to fetch the user location, once the location if fetched animate the camera to specific zoom level and display the marker. I believe you trying is for first time I will encourage you to go through the documentations first. I have done something similar like this, In `SplashScreen` I fetch location using `GoogleApiClient` after fetching, I load the `MapActivity` and I use fetched location in the `Map` with custom `Marker`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code, We can get our location in google map by NETWORK_PROVIDER. NETWORK_PROVIDER pick your location from your WIFI location or your network provider companies like(IDEA,AIRTEL,VODAPHONE) .

```
try {
                    if (googleMap == null) {
                        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                    }
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    LocationManager location_manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    LocationListener listner = new getlatlngListner();
                    location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 2000, listner);
                    location_manager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
mMarkerOptions.visible(true);
mMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Your bitmap));
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                        LatLng mPos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                        mMarkerOptions.position(mPos);
                        mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions);
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mPos));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Do I still need to use the code in my private void setUpMap()

Comment: And if you call the void from the location listener? Or you need to initialize everything in this method?